# Expressão regular para aceitar números e letras, independente da sequência

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso validar um campo de senha com no mínimo 8 caracteres, sendo no mínimo 2 números e o resto letras, eles podem estar em qualquer posição.

12abcdef
abcdef12

A expressão que fiz funciona nos casos acima:

```
function vSenha(senha) {
    return /^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d{2,}).{8,16})|(?=.*\d{2,})(?=.*[a-z]).{8,16})$/.test(senha);

}
```

Porém se eu colocar uma letra e um número intercalados, a expressão não funciona. Eu estava tentando montar um operador *OR* com regex mas não obtive sucesso.

Ex de como não funciona:

1a2b3c4d

Comment: Pode haver outros caracteres que não letras? com o`!?#€%&`?

Comment: @Sergio, nao nao, são só letras mesmo, esqueci de colocar na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de alguns testes a seguinte expressão resolveu o meu problema:

```
function vSenha(senha) {
    return /^((?=(?:.*?[a-z]){1,})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2,})).{8,16}$/.test(senha);
}
```

Os casos abaixo funcionam:

```
12cbahda
1b3c4c3d2a
a1fewfew2
```

Não precisei de nada além disso para funcionar a validação.

Comment: Se forem só numeros a tua regex falha, é isso que queres? Por exemplo `'123456789'`

Comment: Isso, no final ele tem que aceitar no mínimo 2 numeros e o resto letras, pode ser 12345678910abc ou abcdefghj12,

Comment: Esta regex aceita `"$%()!1a2?+"`.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que vai ser dificil uma regex que abranja todos os casos. Seria mais fácil ir contando os caracteres e numeros e verificar no final.

Sugestão:

```js
var testes = ["12abcdef", "abcdef12", "1a2b3c4d", "abcdefghij"];

function vSenha(senha) {
  var numeros = 0;
  var letras = 0;
  var caracteres = senha.split('');
  for (let car of caracteres) {
    if (car.match(/\d/)) numeros++; // se for numero
    else if (car.match(/\w/)) letras++; // se não for numero, pode ser letra
  }
  return numeros >= 2 && (numeros + letras) == senha.length;

}

testes.forEach(teste => console.log(teste, vSenha(teste)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seja mais simples usar duas regex uma para números e outra apenas para letras e depois fazer a verificação dos valores minimos de cada categoria, já que a captura (com o paramêtro `g`) retorna um array. Adicionei um verificação extra que capturas outros caracteres como `#@,._` caso ache algum deles torna a senha inválida.

```
function validarSenha(senha){

    if(senha.length === 0 || senha.match(/\W|_/)){
        console.log('senha invalida');
        return false;
    } 

    var numeros = senha.match(/\d/g) ? senha.match(/\d/g).length : 0;
    var letras = senha.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g) ? senha.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length : 0;
    var totalCaracteresValidos = numeros + letras;
    var tamanhoMinimoSenha = 8;


    if(totalCaracteresValidos >= tamanhoMinimoSenha && numeros >= 2 && !senha.match(/\W|_/)){
       console.log('senha valida');
    }else{
       console.log('senha invalida');
    }
}


validarSenha('12345AAAA'); //válida
validarSenha('12345AAAA#'); //invalida devido ao '#' mesmo tendo 8 mais de caracteres sendo pelo menos 2 dígitos.
validarSenha('1ABC2ccD'); //válida
```

Comment: Tem algum problema a resposta? posso corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Como já dito aqui, apenas com `regex` será difícil conseguir englobar todas as possibilidades, diante disso, segue duas formas de fazer isso:
1ª forma: nessa detalhei um pouco mais para saber quantas letras, quantos números e quantos caracteres inválidos foram inseridos.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  jQuery('#validarSenha').click(function(){
    var senha = $('#senha').val();
    var tamanhoSenha = senha.length;
    //Verifica o tamanho da senha
    if (tamanhoSenha < 8){
      $("#ValidadeSenha").html("Senha Inválida - A senha deve conter pelo menos 8 dígitos!!");
    }
    else {
      var qtdNumeros = 0;
      var qtdLetras = 0;
      var caractereInvalido = 0;
      i = 0;
      //Percorre toda a string verificando cada caractere
      while (i < tamanhoSenha){
        //Verifica se o caractere atual é número letra
        if (senha.charAt(i).match(/\d/)) {
          qtdNumeros++; 
        }
        //Verifica se o caractere atual é letra
        else if (senha.charAt(i).match(/\w/)){
          qtdLetras++;
        }
        //Verifica se o caractere atual é um caractere que não seja letra ou número
        else{
          caractereInvalido++;
        }  
        i++;
      }

      if (qtdNumeros < 2 || caractereInvalido > 0 ){
        $("#ValidadeSenha").html("Senha Inválida - A senha deve conter pelo menos 2 números e deve conter somente letras e números!!");
        console.log("Quantidade de letras: "+qtdLetras);
        console.log("Quantidade de números: "+qtdNumeros);
        console.log("Quantidade de caracteres inválidos: "+caractereInvalido);
      }
      else {
        $("#ValidadeSenha").html("Senha válida!");
        console.log("Quantidade de letras: "+qtdLetras);
        console.log("Quantidade de números: "+qtdNumeros);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Senha <input type="text" id="senha" name="senha" ><p id="ValidadeSenha"></p>
   
<br>
<button id="validarSenha" class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Validar Senha</button>
```

2ª Forma: mais simples, é basicamente a que o [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220548/14213) postou, porém faltou só a questão da validação do tamanho mínimo de 8 dígitos, com isso, a função está deixando passar senhas com menos de 8 dígitos, então só complementei a função dele acrescentando a verificação dos 8 dígitos na última linha da função:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#validarSenha').click(function(){
    var senha = $('#senha').val();
    if (vSenha(senha) == true){
      $("#ValidadeSenha").html("Senha válida!");
    }
    else{
      $("#ValidadeSenha").html("Senha Inválida!");
    }
  });
  function vSenha(senha) {
    var numeros = 0;
    var letras = 0;
    var caracteres = senha.split('');
    for (let car of caracteres) {
      if (car.match(/\d/)) numeros++; // se for numero
      else if (car.match(/\w/)) letras++; // se não for numero, pode ser letra
    }
    return numeros >= 2 && (numeros + letras) == senha.length && senha.length >= 8;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Senha <input type="text" id="senha" name="senha" ><p id="ValidadeSenha"></p>
   
<br>
<button id="validarSenha" class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Validar Senha</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você ate pode montar uma REGEX para isso, mas ela seria enorme, justamente pelo fato de **não ser regular**, já que os números podem estar em qualquer lugar da senha.

O ideal no seu caso é montar um algoritmo como [sugerido pelo @sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220548/14213)

#### Sugestão minha :

```js
function checkPass(pass){
  var len = pass.length;
  var num = pass.replace(/\D/g, '').length;
  var wrong = pass.replace(/[a-z0-9]/gi, '').length; // REMOVE TUDO QUE VOCÊ QUER, CASO HAJA CARACTERES QUE VOCÊ NÃO QUER ELES ESTARAO AQUI.
  return len >= 8 && num >= 2 && !(wrong > 0);
}

var testes = ["12abcdef", "abcdef12", "1a2b3c4d", "abcdefghij", "1a2b$3c4d"];

for(var i=0;i<testes.length;i++){
  console.log(testes[i], checkPass(testes[i]));
}
```

Comment: você consegue me mostrar por que a regex ^((?=(?:.*?[a-z]){1,})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2,})).+$ é pior do que esse algoritmo?

Comment: Na teoria da informática, as linguagens regulares são um subconjunto estrito de linguagens livres de contexto, mas as implementações de expressões regulares em linguagens de programação convencionais são mais poderosas. Os motores regex compatíveis com Perl são Turing completos. Um regex pode realmente corresponder além de linguagens regulares.

Answer (score 1):

**Condições**

1. 8+ caracteres, só números ou letras:

   ```javascript
   /^[a-z\d]{8,}$/i
   ```
2. Mínimo 2 números:

   ```javascript
   /^(?:.*?\d){2}/
   ```
3. Mínimo 1 letra:

   ```javascript
   /^.*?[a-z]/i
   ```

**Todo junto**

```javascript
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){2})[a-z\d]{8,}$/i
```

Para unir condições diferentes na mesma expressão, precisa de um [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead).
O lookahead não casa caracteres na posição atual, mas dá uma *espiada* adiante. Se a asserção corresponde, retorna à posição atual, sem consumir caracteres.

**Código**

```javascript
function vSenha(senha) {
    var regex = /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(?:.*?\d){2})[a-z\d]{8,}$/i;
    return regex.test(senha);
}
```

Comment: Eu ia postar a mesma REGEX ai vi que você ja tinha posto, a unica diferença é que estava usando o `.*?` (operador não guloso)

Comment: @Guilherme É verdade que é um pouco mais eficiente. A solução com o melhor resultado seria usar uma lista negada ([JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/guloso-vs-nao-guloso/1)). Escolhi `.*` para mantê-lo simples, mas vejo que o AP já usou `.*?`. Editei.

Comment: Verifiquei o testador que mandou varias vezes e o operador `.*?` ainda foi mais rápido. Pela logica a lista negada seria mais lenta pois ainda incluiria a verificação de checar se o carácter não esta na lista, já o `.` captura tudo então não tem essa verificação. [Teste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNcZF.png)

Comment: @Guilherme o ponto también verifica que não case `\n`. A lista negada geralmente tem um maior tempo de compilação, mas um tempo de execução menor. No entanto, como qualquer regex, isso depende de muitas coisas, muitas otimizações, e especialmente da string. Meus resultados [FF53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WClQh.png), [Chrome59](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idNtX.png), [Chrome57/Android N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2HHb.png)... Isso aumenta para casos válidos: [JSPerf 2](https://jsperf.com/nao-gulosa-vs-x-lista-negada/1).

Answer (score -3):

Cara, tem como porque é uma expressão regular sim.
Link do exemplo no regexr: https://regexr.com/5p75r

Explicando a regex:

- `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%\^&*()]{8,32}$)` garante que do início ao fim, deve ter de 8 a 32 caracteres que esteja entre os caracteres do bloco
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]))` obriga que tenha um caractere de [a-z] dentre os vários diferentes dele, uma vez (implicito)
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){1})` obriga que tenha um caractere de [A-Z] dentre os vários diferentes dele, uma vez (explicito)
- `(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3})` obriga que tenha um caractere de [0-9] dentre os vários diferentes dele, três vezes (explicito)
- `(?=(?:[^!@#$%&*()]*[!@#$%&*()]){1})` obriga que tenha um caractere de [!@#$%&*()] dentre os vários diferentes dele, uma vez (explicito)
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*()]*)$` permite a combinação desorganizada entre as regras, fazendo com que possa se realizar o cumprimentos das expressões desordenadamente (?=)